# How can I assign a specific function to different HTML pages in one JS file?

Tags: javascript, html, function

Having 2 similar pages, displaying tables with different data, in the HTML I call each specific funtion to output the data. Each table has its own id, and specific funtion on JS as shown below. One of the pages shows well the data tables, but the other one no.

Browser console shows: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
     at leastLoyal (senate_attendance.js:106)
    at senate_attendance.js:108

How can i solve This?

JS:

```
//FIRST HTML TABLE 1
function leastLoyal(){
  function loyalPartySort(a,b) {
  if (a.votes_with_party_pct < b.votes_with_party_pct)
    return -1;
  if (a.votes_with_party_pct > b.votes_with_party_pct)
    return 1;
  return 0;
  }
  newArr.sort(loyalPartySort);

  var datos3="<tr><th>" + headersSenateLoyalty.Name + "</th><th>"+ headersSenateLoyalty. NumRepsAtt + "</th><th>" + headersSenateLoyalty.PctParty+ "</th><th>";
  for(var i=0; i<10; i++){
  datos3+="<tr><td><a target='_blank' href=" + newArr[i].nameLink + ">"+ newArr[i].fullName + "</a></td><td>" + newArr[i].votParty
   + "</td><td>" + newArr[i].votes_with_party_pct + "</td>";
    }
  document.getElementById("senateLeast").innerHTML=datos3;
}
leastLoyal()
//FIRST HTML TABLE 2
function mostLoyal(){
  function loyalPartySort(a,b) {
  if (a.votes_with_party_pct > b.votes_with_party_pct)
    return -1;
  if (a.votes_with_party_pct < b.votes_with_party_pct)
    return 1;
  return 0;
  }
  newArr.sort(loyalPartySort);

  var datos4="<tr><th>" + headersSenateLoyalty.Name + "</th><th>"+ headersSenateLoyalty. NumRepsAtt + "</th><th>" + headersSenateLoyalty.PctParty+ "</th><th>";
  for(var i=0; i<10; i++){
  datos4+="<tr><td><a target='_blank' href=" + newArr[i].nameLink + ">"+ newArr[i].fullName + "</a></td><td>" + newArr[i].votParty
   + "</td><td>" + newArr[i].votes_with_party_pct + "</td>";
    }
  document.getElementById("senateMost").innerHTML=datos4;
}
mostLoyal()
//SECOND HTML TABLE 1
function leastEnga(){
  function attPartySort(a,b) {
  if (a.missed_votes_pct < b.missed_votes_pct)
    return -1;
  if (a.missed_votes_pct > b.missed_votes_pct)
    return 1;
  return 0;
  }
  newArr.sort(attPartySort);

  var datos5="<tr><th>" + headersSenateAtt.Name + "</th><th>"+ headersSenateAtt.NumMissVot + "</th><th>" + headersSenateAtt.PctMiss+ "</th><th>";
  for(var i=0; i<10; i++){
  datos5+="<tr><td><a target='_blank' href=" + newArr[i].nameLink + ">"+ newArr[i].fullName + "</a></td><td>" + newArr[i].missVot
   + "</td><td>" + newArr[i].missed_votes_pct + "</td>";
    }
  document.getElementById("senateLeastAtt").innerHTML=datos5;
}
leastEnga()
//SECOND HTML TABLE 2
function mostEnga(){
  function attPartySort(a,b) {
  if (a.missed_votes_pct > b.missed_votes_pct)
    return -1;
  if (a.missed_votes_pct < b.missed_votes_pct)
    return 1;
  return 0;
  }
  newArr.sort(attPartySort);

  var datos2="<tr><th>" + headersSenateAtt.Name + "</th><th>"+ headersSenateAtt.NumMissVot + "</th><th>" + headersSenateAtt.PctMiss+ "</th><th>";
  for(var i=0; i<10; i++){
  datos2+="<tr><td><a target='_blank' href=" + newArr[i].nameLink + ">"+ newArr[i].fullName + "</a></td><td>" + newArr[i].missVot
   + "</td><td>" + newArr[i].missed_votes_pct + "</td>";
    }
  document.getElementById("senateMostAtt").innerHTML=datos2;
}
mostEnga()
```

FIRST HTML

```
<div class="w-100"></div>
        <div class="col-6"><h2>Least Loyal (Bottom 10% of Party)</h2></div>
        <div class="col-6"><h2>Most Loyal (Top 10% of Party)</h2></div>
        <div class="w-100"></div>
        <div class="col-6">
        <table onload="function()" class="table table-hover table-sm" id="senateLeast"></table></div>
        <div class="col-6">
        <table onload="function()" class="table table-hover table-sm" id="senateMost">
        </table></div>
```

SECOND HTML

```
<div class="w-100"></div>
        <div class="col-6"><h2>Least Engaged (Bottom 10% Attendance)</h2></div>
        <div class="col-6"><h2>Most Engaged (Top 10% Attendance)</h2></div>
        <div class="w-100"></div>
        <div class="col-6">
        <table onload="lastEnga()" class="table table-hover table-sm" id="senateLeastAtt"></table></div>
        <div class="col-6">
        <table onload="mostEnga()" class="table table-hover table-sm" id="senateMostAtt">
        </table></div>
```

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: What research have you done? Numerous ways to approach this issue and should be an easy web search to at least get a starting point. Basic research is expected here before asking general questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem is that you're running each function after defining it, so all 4 functions get run on both tables.

```
function leastLoyal(){
   // ...
}
leastLoyal() // <-- remove this
```

Remove the function call after each function.

Second, `onload` will not fire on a `table`. You can put the attribute on the body instead:

```
<body onload="leastEnga();mostEnga()">
    ...
    <div class="col-6">
        <table class="table table-hover table-sm" id="senateLeastAt"></table>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
        <table class="table table-hover table-sm" id="senateMostAtt">
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

You're also using a lot of undefined variables in the functions so I'm hoping this isn't the full code.